# Calculate the total saving by integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question is:
I plan to save for $25$ yrs to buy a home by cash purchase. My first deposit is $10000\$$ at age $22$. Each year I plan to increase my saving by $10\%$ compared to the preceding year saving. How much money have I saved after $25$ yrs ?

So, this can be solved by geometric progression and the answer is $1091818\$$.

But I have a thought that I could use integral of compound interest formula to find the total
$$P = ae^{rt}$$

However, the answer(from integration) that I get is wrong, i.e., $118300$

I couldn't find my mistake. Kindly help me with this question. Thanks

Comment: Integration helps you solve continuous change problems with infinitesimal intervals. This is a discrete change problem with finite intervals.

Comment: So I couldn't use Integration to solve this problem right? @Deepak

Comment: No, just use geometric sum.